# What does "to make determinations on something" mean in the following?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have grabbed the following text from a book learning **Programming Languages**:

> OK, so what approach should you take within your application **to make
> determinations  on configuration** based on the development environment
> (e.g., use this connection string  for Development and this one for
> Production)? Well there are a number of different  answers to that; to
> my mind there are two broad approaches:
>
> 1. “Manually” determine the environment in your code, and take the  necessary action.
> 2. Leverage the power and behavior of the .NET Core  Configuration API. We’re going to go with option 2. While option 1 is a possibility
>    (indeed this pattern is  used in many of the default .NET Core
>    Projects – see the following example), I personally  prefer to
>    decouple code from configuration where possible, although it’s not
>    always  possible – that is why we’ll go with option 2.

Could anyone tell me what the highlighted part above mean?

Comment: "on" in this context means "regarding." You are "making determinations" (not very idiomatic) regarding the configuration of your application.

Answer (score 3):

"to make determinations on configuration" is a complex and confusing way of saying "determine configuration" or "decide on configuration" -- i.e. figure out connection strings, etc.

It is common for technical people to make English sentences overly complex and difficult to understand.  For example, this writer converts the verb "determine" to a noun "determinations" and makes the sentence more complex.

Comment: But I thought that it means "**to decide which approach to choose inside the configuration**  ", Does it make sense too?